# Minecraft - Pick a block in creative mode If I don't have a mouse?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just got Minecraft today and I got really excited that I wanted to build something. I don't have a mouse and the computer didn't come with one.. SO If their is button I need to press to choose a block please let me know. Do I press a button or do I have to buy a 3 buttoned mouse?

Comment: then buy a mouse with scroll wheel. playing with the laptop pad is really distasteful.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean picking a block as using the middle button(Button 3) to pick block in the Minecraft World, you can change it in your Controls. Else, Amitai's answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can press E to open up the item browser, but you might need to get a mouse to place it down.

Answer (score 0):

if it's a laptop then you can use the mouse pad but if it's a desktop you're most likely unable to play Minecraft until you get a mouse.

Comment: It seems like OP has a 1-2 button mouse, judging by how they can play the game to the point that they want to use that specific keybind.  Also note that mice can be emulated, and a physical mouse is not always needed (but if OP was emulating a mouse, they would also know how to emulate the third mouse button)

Answer (score -2):

Its impossible to play Minecraft without a mouse. You can't look around. But if you want to pick block, just press ESC, click options then controls and change pick block from 3rd mouse button to something else.

Comment: I think the question is meant as "I only have a touchpad/pointing stick/trackball/mouse control with numpad/...". But even if not, ChilledOut already wrote what you wrote.